# Are there useful applications for the Divisible Type Class?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, elm, type-theory

I've lately been working on an API in Elm where one of the main types is contravariant. So, I've googled around to see what one can do with contravariant types and found that [the Contravariant package in Haskell defines the Divisible type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.2/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html).

It is defined as follows:

```
class Contravariant f => Divisible f where
  divide  :: (a -> (b, c)) -> f b -> f c -> f a
  conquer :: f a
```

It turns out that my particular type does suit the definition of the Divisible type class. While Elm does not support type classes, I do look at Haskell from time to time for some inspiration.

My question: Are there any practical uses for this type class? Are there known APIs out there in Haskell (or other languages) that benefit from this divide-conquer pattern? Are there any gotchas I should be aware of?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ed Kmett's been working on making Fritz Henglein's generalizations of radix sort practical. It turns out that these "discriminators" are natural Divisibles and much of the technique can be written out along the lines of that type class https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination

Comment: Oh wow, that's impressive. That's pretty much the last place I'd ever think to use a type class.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson you should formulate your comment into an answer because it deserves all of the upvotes.  Especially if you include code samples ^_^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll examine the example of the core data types in Fritz Henglein's generalized radix sort techniques as implemented by Edward Kmett in the [discrimination](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination) package.

While there's a great deal going on there, it largely focuses around a type like this

```
data Group a = Group (forall b . [(a, b)] -> [[b]])
```

If you have a value of type `Group a` you essentially must have an equivalence relationship on `a` because if I give you an association between `a`s and some type `b` completely unknown to you then you can give me "groupings" of `b`.

```
groupId :: Group a -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupId (Group grouper) = grouper . map (\a -> (a, a))
```

You can see this as a core type for writing a utility library of groupings. For instance, we might want to know that if we can `Group a` and `Group b` then we can `Group (a, b)` (more on this in a second). Henglein's core idea is that if you can start with some basic `Group`s on integers—we can write very fast `Group Int32` implementations via radix sort—and then use combinators to extend them over all types then you will have generalized radix sort to algebraic data types.

---

So how might we build our combinator library?

Well, `f :: Group a -> Group b -> Group (a, b)` is pretty important in that it lets us make groups of product-like types. Normally, we'd get this from `Applicative` and `liftA2` but `Group`, you'll notice, is `Contravaiant`, not a `Functor`.

So instead we use `Divisible`

```
divided :: Group a -> Group b -> Group (a, b)
```

Notice that this arises in a strange way from

```
divide :: (a -> (b, c)) -> Group b -> Group c -> Group a
```

as it has the typical "reversed arrow" character of contravariant things. We can now understand things like `divide` and `conquer` in terms of their interpretation on `Group`.

**Divide** says that if I want to build a strategy for equating `a`s using strategies for equating `b`s and `c`s, I can do the following for any type `x`

1. Take your partial relation `[(a, x)]` and map over it with a function `f :: a -> (b, c)`, and a little tuple manipulation, to get a new relation `[(b, (c, x))]`.
2. Use my `Group b` to discriminate `[(b, (c, x))]` into `[[(c, x)]]`
3. Use my `Group c` to discriminate each `[(c, x)]` into `[[x]]` giving me `[[[x]]]`
4. Flatten the inner layers to get `[[x]]` like we need

   ```
   instance Divisible Group where
     conquer = Group $ return . fmap snd
     divide k (Group l) (Group r) = Group $ \xs ->
       -- a bit more cleverly done here...
       l [ (b, (c, d)) | (a,d) <- xs, let (b, c) = k a] >>= r
   ```

We also get interpretations of the more tricky [`Decidable` refinement of `Divisible`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.3.1.1/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html#t:Decidable)

```
class Divisible f => Decidable f where
  lose   :: (a -> Void) -> f a
  choose :: (a -> Either b c) -> f b -> f c -> f a

instance Decidable Group where
  lose   :: (a -> Void) -> Group a
  choose :: (a -> Either b c) -> Group b -> Group c -> Group a
```

These read as saying that for any type `a` of which we can guarantee there are no values (we cannot produce values of `Void` by any means, a function `a -> Void` is a means of producing `Void` given `a`, thus we must not be able to produce values of `a` by any means either!) then we immediately get a grouping of zero values

```
lose _ = Group (\_ -> [])
```

We also can go a similar game as to `divide` above except instead of sequencing our use of the input discriminators, we alternate.

---

Using these techniques we build up a library of "`Group`able" things, namely [`Grouping`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination-0.1/docs/Data-Discrimination.html#t:Grouping)

```
class Grouping a where
  grouping :: Group a
```

and note that [nearly all the definitions arise](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination-0.1/docs/src/Data-Discrimination-Grouping.html#Grouping) from the basic definition atop `groupingNat` which uses fast monadic vector manipuations to achieve an efficient radix sort.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your detailed answer. I have noticed the need for the divided function (which I called `zip`) and it's nice to see that validated so wonderfully here. I have a question about the refining of divisible. Given the existence of conquer (or lose), wouldn't it better if divide were defined as `divide :: (a -> Maybe (b, c)) -> f b -> f c -> f a`? With `conquer`, we can handle the case where trying to split `a` yields nothing. For example, with a binary tree, one can split a branch in two and get the subtrees, but the leaves cannot be split.

Answer (score 21):

One example:

Applicative is useful for parsing, because you can turn Applicative parsers of parts into a parser of wholes, needing only a pure function for combining the parts into a whole.

Divisible is useful for serializing (should we call this coparsing now?), because you can turn Divisible serializers of parts into a serializer of wholes, needing only a pure function for splitting the whole into parts.

I haven't actually seen a project that worked this way, but I'm (slowly) working on an Avro implementation for Haskell that does.

When I first came across Divisible I wanted it for `divide`, and had no idea what possible use `conquer` could be other than cheating (an `f a` out of nowhere, for any `a`?). But to make the Divisible laws check out for my serializers `conquer` became a "serializer" that encodes anything to zero bytes, which makes a lot of sense.

Comment: People call the opposite of parsing "pretty printing". Admittedly, I like coparsing more :).

Comment: This is an interesting perspective because my use case is very similar. Basically, I have another type that is applicative and I see the two types as a sort of duality working in opposite directions but in lockstep. I think the serializing/deserializing argument is interesting and would be interested in seeing such an API with example code to get an idea of the usability of the API.

Comment: @TheSeamau5 I'm experimenting with an approach where I'm polymorphic in the functor type, using a type class that requires it to be *either* Applicative or Divisible. This means user-defined structures require *both* a combiner function and a splitter function, and work out of the box on all of my several parsers and encoders, plus on any future Avro schema interpreters I write.

Comment: @Ben so, if I understand correctly, your library provides functions that automatically work on a whole bunch of decoders (applicative) and encoders (divisible)?

Comment: @TheSeamau5 Basically yes. If you have an `f a`, an `f b`, (where `f` is constrained to implement an `Avro` type class and a `Polyvariant` type class), plus a function `a -> b -> r`, and a function `r -> (a, b)`, then you (thrid party code) can make an `f r` without needing to choose an implementation of `f`. This lets you build up a complex Avro schema which can be used as an encoder or decoder (or for reconciliation of different-but-compatible schemas, etc). (The actual approach for Avro is different, because there are record headers and such, but that's the idea).

Comment: @TheSeamau5 Polyvariant is my slightly dumb name for a type constructor that is known to be either a covariant Applicative functor, or a contravariant Divisible functor, but which it is isn't known. Instances only need the Applicative/Divisible instance and a single line declaration.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the detail. Your comments have made me wonder a bit and I have a question. Wouldn't it be better if the divide function were defined to have the type `(a -> Maybe (b, c)) -> f b -> f c -> f a`? Because I'm thinking that if you have some sort of recursive schema where a,b,c all happen to be of the same type (for example a binary tree), you may want to capture the fact that you have reached the very bottom of the tree by just returing Nothing. For example, the splitter on a binary tree would return the two subtrees, but if it's a leaf node you just want to return Nothing

Comment: Or perhaps more generally: `(a -> g b c) -> f b -> f c -> f a`

Answer (score 16):

Here's a possible use case.

In streaming libraries, one can have fold-like constructs like the ones from the [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.1.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html) package, that are fed a sequence of inputs and return a summary value when the sequence is exhausted.

These folds are contravariant on their inputs, and can be made `Divisible`. This means that if you have a stream of elements where each element can be somehow decomposed into `b` and `c` parts, and you also happen to have a fold that consumes `b`s and another fold that consumes `c`s, then you can build a fold that consumes the original stream.

The actual folds from `foldl` don't implement `Divisible`, but they could, using a newtype wrapper. In my `process-streaming` package I have a [fold-like type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-streaming-0.7.2.2/docs/System-Process-Streaming.html#t:SiphonOp) that does implement `Divisible`.

`divide` requires the return values of the constituent folds to be of the same type, and that type must be an instance of `Monoid`. If the folds return different, unrelated monoids, a workaround is to put each return value in a separate field of a tuple, leaving the other field as `mempty`. This works because a tuple of monoids is itself a `Monoid`.

Comment: This is interesting. It seems that, in playing around with these types, that there has to be a way of merging the inputs so the instance of monoid does make a lot of sense.

One of the cool things though with the folds is that you can chain the operations with applicative combinators. (i.e. `<*>`) I wonder if there is an equivalent to that in the Divisible world that provides that sort of chaining.